# Can i have a simple script on sheet1 and sheet2?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a script that automatically sorts data when i make a change. It workds fine on the one sheet but i cannot find a way to apply it on sheet2 too.

So i need it to sort both sheet1 and 2 (the sheets are simular so the same sort range and everything needs to be the same - i just need it to apply on sheet2 also-

I have tried to make a copy of the code and change sheet_name to sheet2.

I Insert picture of the code. I would be very happy if you could help.

[image]

Comment: Btw, i dont know how to code - so if you could send what the exact code would look like i would be very very very happy :-)

Comment: You should post your script into the question to give posters more information about the scope of the solution.

Comment: I cant copy it - it says our post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: I but i have added a screenshot of the code :-)

Comment: Jakob, what @garrilla told you is you should post code/not image, because that way people that would like to help you don't have to retype it! also you can paste your code and use ctrl+k to indent it..

Comment: I know but i am trying. But it says Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. when i paste it even though i use CTRL+K

Comment: any reason for deletion? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563227/count-date-with-countifs-function-google-sheet

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

- Take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). This will give you very important information regarding the edit/event which took place.
- The idea is to use the script for multiple sheets. One way to do that is to construct an array of the sheet names you want to include:

  ```
  const sheet_names = ["Management Associate","Finance Associate"];
  ```

  and check if the name of the active sheet is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in this list:

  ```
  if(sheet_names.includes(sheet.getName())){
  // the rest of the code here
  }
  ```
- As a more complete implementation, I modified the last line of your code to include the name of the sheet that was edited. To do that, I used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but of course this approach is optional:

  ```
   ss.toast(`Sort complete in ${sheet.getName()}`);
  ```

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   const sheet_names = ["Management Associate","Finance Associate"]; // add sheets here
   const sort_data_range = "A2:H999";
   const sort_order = [{column:6, ascending:true}];
   const ss = e.source;
   const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   if(sheet_names.includes(sheet.getName())){
        const range = sheet.getRange(sort_data_range);
        range.sort(sort_order);
   }
   ss.toast(`Sort complete in ${sheet.getName()}`);
}
```

Comment: What would i do the sheets names very Finance Associate and Management Associate for instance

Comment: I tried changing

const sheet_names = ["sheet1","sheet2]; to const sheet_names = ["Management Associate","Finance Associate"]; and at the same time changing  if(sheet_names.includes(sheet.getName())){ to  if(sheet_names.includes(Associate.getName())){ but nothing worked

Comment: I will - but i still doesnt sort in the Finance Associate Sheet - it says "Finanace Associate" updated but nothing happens and the sheet naes are correct written in code and sheet

Comment: @Jakob your original question was `how to apply this code to a different sheet`. Well this is the answer of your question. If you have multiple questions you need to ask them in separate posts. Stackoverflow does not allow follow up questions and it is not a service of free code. You need to do an exhaustive research before you ask here and provide your research efforts. This is also how you are going to learn.

Comment: @Jakob also it is common sense to understand that I am not able to fix your code that sorts your data if you haven't shown a bit of what your sheet looks like. Do you really believe you provided enough information in this post for someone to fix your sorting code ? This is why you need to post a new question to provide more **details** and relevant information of your sheet.